# Installing Kingbase Database

Tags: database

I have been trying to install KingbaseES Database and I followed the instructions here. Everything went fine. In the end, when I try to start the program using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kingbase-xe start
```

It gives me:

```
[ ok ] Starting kingbase-xe (via systemctl): kingbase-xe.service.
```

Which is what I need. But I cannot access the "localhost:8080"? any ways to fix that? or maybe I did not install it properly.

Comment: Please start with OS & release details.

Comment: we do not support Ubuntu 14.04 ;-)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413269/creating-new-database-on-kingbasees-database ;-)